# Need explanation of this Javascript String Capitalise Protoype

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Using the following bits of code:

CSS:

```
input   {background-color:black; text-transform:capitalize;}
```

JS:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() { 
    return this.replace( /(^|\s)([a-z])/g , function(m,p1,p2){ 
        return p1+p2.toUpperCase(); 
     }); 
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="if1" onfocus="enterInp(this.id)" onblur="exitInp(this.id)" />
```

I was surprised to find that the value of the input text field was not capitalized even though it is displayed correctly on the screen, so I looked for a way to do it.  The script above was gleaned from a web site that didn't provide a Q&A facility and, although it works fine, I don't understand exactly how it works and I have been unable to find an explanation - I don't have access to a Javascript manual.

The bit I don't understand is the function that is emboldened.  Using `alert` I have discovered that for each word that is capitalized the `m` and `p2` parameters contain the letter to be capitalized and `p1` appears to be `null`.

Could someone tell me where these `m`, `p1`, `p2` parameters come from and how they get set?

Comment: It is explained in the [MDN `.replace()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Comment: Thank you for the succinct response - it tells me everything I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters use in the anonymous replace function come from the matched elements in the regex `/(^|\s)([a-z])/g`. Matched elements are berween brackets, `p1` is a line start or a space, `p2` is a lower case letter and `m` is just the whole matched regex.

The function will concat the matched elements and set upper case to the first letter following a line start or a white space.

The input value won't be chaged since `capitalize` is only used for display but there is no call to this function in javascript code.

Comment: Now that I've read the item in the MDN as indicated by Felix Kling I now think I understand the implications of the answer from @sinsedrix - for each set of () 'capturing parentheses' in the regexp a p1, p2, ... parameter is created.  Correct?

Comment: Apologies, now I've re-read the MDN item I see my comment above is correct, though maybe not well written.  Many thanks for your help.